# Por qué no me compila esta clase?

Tags: java

Alguien sabe porque no me compila?
Estoy practicando con numeros pares lo basico y al parecer no agarra los `{ }`

```
public class NumeroPar {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int numero = 7;
  
    if (numero > 0) {
    if (numero % 2 == 0);
            System.out.println("El numero introducido es Par");    
    } else {
            System.out.println("EL numero introducido es impar");    
    }
    } else {
            System.out.println("Introduce algun numero positivo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola? Algún error cuando no te compila? Si lo hay, por favor edita tu pregunta y ponlo junto con el resto

Answer (score 0):

Tu código debería de verse tal que así :

```
public class NumeroPar {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int numero = 7;
    if (numero > 0) {
        if (numero % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("El numero introducido es Par");  
        }
        else 
             System.out.println("EL numero introducido es impar");   
        
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Introduce algun numero positivo");
    }
}
```

Primero de todo, te recomiendo que utilices tabulaciones para entender mejor a que parte de código pertenece cada `if/else`, esto te servira en un futuro cuando tengas un gran código de bloque para entender el funcionamiento del código.

**Tu problema principal ha sido en :**

`if (numero % 2 == 0);` --> Has utilizado `;` en vez de  `}`

Tampoco es necesario que utilices `else {}`, puedes simplemente hacer `else` segudio de tu código

**Asignar valor de la variable por teclado**
Para que el valor de una variable depende del valor entrado por el usuario mediante teclado puedes utilizar el objeto `Scanner`.

Primero de todo importamos la libreria `java.util.*;` y inicializamos una variable del objeto Scanner de la siguiente forma :

`import java.util.*;`

`Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);` -> Donde teclado es la variable que puedes llamar como quieras.

Seguido de esto modificas tu variable `numero` de forma que su valor se entre utilizando el teclado.
`int numero = teclado.nextInt();`

Hecho esto, ya puedes leer valores entrados por teclado y almacenarlos en variables.
**Ejemplo con tu código**

```
import java.util.*;
public class NumeroPar {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numero = teclado.nextInt();
    if (numero > 0) {
        if (numero % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("El numero introducido es Par");  
        }
        else 
             System.out.println("EL numero introducido es impar");   
        
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Introduce algun numero positivo");
    }
}
```

**Otros ejemplos de almacenamientos utilizando Scanner**
`String frase = teclado.nextLine();` --> Leer string
`double decimal = teclado.nextDouble()` --> Leer double
`char letra = teclado.next().charAt(0)` --> Leer char
`boolean bool = teclado.nextBoolean()` --> Leer boolean

Comment: Perdon ahora entiendo muchas gracias, si quiero poner en vez de 

int numero = 7:

Quiero que la persona ingrese un  numero como seria?

Comment: Ahora te actualizo la respuesta con lo que pides no te preocupes.

Comment: Sos un genio!! gracias de verdad!

Answer (score -3):

Tienes errores en las llaves. No estás abriendo la llave del `else` final. Debería ser así:

```
int numero = 8;

if (numero > 0) {
  if (numero % 2 == 0){
    System.out.println("El numero introducido es Par");
  } else {
    System.out.println("EL numero introducido es impar"); 
  }
} else {
  System.out.println("Introduce algun numero positivo");
}
```

Comment: No utilices imágenes, simplemente añade el código en formato de texto utilizando ``````CODIGO```````. Añade también una explicación si crees que es conveniente

Comment: "Errores en las llaves" ... ¿cuales errores? ¿cómo se corrigen?